# Issue when pull from docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am a completely newbie in docker and I want to create my first Docker image. I am started with tutorial https://deis.com/blog/2015/creating-sharing-first-docker-image/ but I stucked on docker pull step.

I've created https://hub.docker.com/r/arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver/ , but when I trying to run

```
docker pull arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver
```

I am getting error

```
docker pull arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: manifest for arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver:latest not found
root@scw-97b47e:/home/Redis_Docker_Image/qqq#
```

How to fix this issue?

Thank you!

**Update 1:**
Something wrong on my side. My Dockerfile is

```
FROM maven:latest

MAINTAINER ArtUrlWWW <email.id@here> 

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y rsync
```

OK, build looks OK for me:

```
 docker build -t mavenlatestwebserver .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   2.56kB
Step 1/4 : FROM maven:latest
 ---> 88714384d642
Step 2/4 : MAINTAINER ArtUrlWWW <email.id@here>
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 850fc0ff0903
Step 3/4 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> cfdc327fa6c2
Step 4/4 : RUN apt-get install -y rsync
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8e6b64a1a3f5
Successfully built 8e6b64a1a3f5
Successfully tagged mavenlatestwebserver:latest
```

But `push` doesn't work:

```
 docker push mavenlatestwebserver
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/library/mavenlatestwebserver]
93223539f002: Preparing
1a5a1b1ca389: Preparing
e32a2ff74ef3: Preparing
9b78bc392c51: Preparing
93c45fd31089: Preparing
a07cd0e5de92: Waiting
cecc20f349f8: Waiting
c9e908787496: Waiting
c7ff02c44ca2: Waiting
555f98a2316c: Waiting
b0220a5743fa: Waiting
995042ba10ad: Waiting
fe40be59465f: Waiting
cf4ecb492384: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Another push is not working too:

```
docker push arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver
```

What am doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Docker Hub page it says: *Last pushed: never*

You will need to build and push the image first. That is:

```
docker build -t your-image .
docker login (it will prompt your credentials
docker push your-image
```

Comment: I've updated my post, can I ask you to look at my post again? Thank you!

Comment: Aaaaaaaahhhhhhhhhh! )))

Comment: `docker build -t arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver .` and `docker push arturlwww/mavenlatestwebserver` )))